# Web API: POST or PUT for creating a new revision of a resource?

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing a RESTful service using Web API. The service is responsible for managing products. Products can be created, deleted and updated. Here is my current Web API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public ProductsController(IProductService productService)
    {
        this._productService = productService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetProductById")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        return this.Ok(this._productService.Get(id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Product product)
    {
        var newProductId = this._productService.Add(product);
        var routeValues = new
                              {
                                  controller = "Products",
                                  id = newProductId
                              };
        return this.CreatedAtRoute("GetProductById", routeValues, null);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] Product product)
    {
        this._productService.Edit(product);
        return this.Ok();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        this._productService.Delete(id);
        return this.Ok();
    }

}
```

A new requirement has come in, such that depending on the scenario, products are updated according to either of the following flows:

1. A new revision of the product, with a new ID, is created in the database. Eventually, once the new revision goes live, the previous revision will be archived.
2. The product is updated in the database as-is, without creating a new revision. The ID of the product will therefore remain the same.

My understanding is that a PUT request satisfies point 2. But what about point 1?  Should it be implemented as a PUT or a POST request? I'm thinking it should be a PUT request as, from a consuming point of view, the product is being updated, even though behind the-scenes a new record gets created.

If I were to implement it as a PUT, then should the `Put` method in my controller return the id of the product, to cater for point 1 above (as the new product revision has a new ID)? Or should I create two separate methods to cater for each of the above points?

Comment: Well, that's a long and old discussion, PUT for insert or PUT for update? anyway, choose the one that you like and ensure that you do the update on the left method, don't do insert and update on the same verb.